# Updated SDK, can't update adt

Tags: android, sdk, adt, development-environment

I updated my SDKs using the SDK manager. Now while launching Eclipse adt it says location not set. Open pref.. And on selecting sdk folder, it says "you need adt version 22.0 or more." where do I update it? downloading a new one is not possible as it will take a whole day with my internet speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can update **ADT plugin v22 from android dev guide** and install use below steps:

Start Eclipse,

1. then select Help > Install New Software.
2. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
4. Select the downloaded ADT-22.0.0.zip file and click OK.
5. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
6. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
7. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.

When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Plase download latest ADT from belwo link...

**"http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html "**

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Eclipse > Help > Check for Update. It will show you if a new adt is available for downloading

Answer (score 0):

You can download [ADT-22.0.1.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.1.zip), and install it.